# YamDocument to text representation end with 3 dots

Tags: c#, .net, yaml, yamldotnet

When I do :

```
var root = new YamlMappingNode();
var doc = new YamlDocument(root);
root.Add("one", "two");
var stream = new YamlStream(doc);
var buffer = new StringBuilder();
using (var writer = new StringWriter(buffer))
{
  stream.Save(writer, false);
  var t = buffer.ToString();
}
```

I get :

```
one: two
...
```

Why is there 3 dots at the end of the file ?

Comment: ok, it seems to be part of the specs. Is there a way to don't append it at the end of the file ?

Comment: YamlStream is used for streaming multiple yaml files down a single stream. Was this intended, or are you just setting out to save a yaml file?

Comment: it was not intended. I wanted to save a single file in memory to a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So `YamlStream` is for streaming multiple yaml documents down a single stream, therefore it codifies markers to indicate both end-of-file (`---`) and end-of-stream (`...`). If you're only serializing a single document, you probably don't want this.

Instead, use `Serializer` to write a node to a `StreamWriter` (backed-off by a (`File`)`Stream`):

```
var serializer = new Serializer(); //YamlDotNet.Serialization.Serializer
using (var fs = File.OpenWrite("some/path.yaml"))
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    serializer.Serialize(sw, doc.RootNode);
}
```